# How can I combine UDAF with functions in an groupby-aggregate expression?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to develope a custom describe. For do that, I will combine functions from pyspark.sql.functions with other **user aggregated customized functions(UDAF)**.
The code looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from scipy.stats import entropy



# Define a UDAF
@pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def my_entropy(data):

    p_data = data.value_counts()           # counts occurrence of each value
    s = entropy(p_data)  # get entropy from counts
    return s


# Perform a groupby-agg 
groupby_col = "a_column"
agg_col = "another_column"
df2return = df\
    .groupBy(groupby_cols)\
    .agg(count(agg_col).alias("count"),
        my_entropy(agg_col).alias("s"))

df2return.show()
```

The error thrown is very long, so I only copy the last exception arised.

[image: y]

Do someone know how to fix that?